# Python different autocorrelation with FFT and non-FFT

Tags: fft, python, autocorrelation, scipy

Im trying to calculate the autocorrelation of soundwaves when I noticed that I get different results with scipys FFT based and with numpys methods.

The 4 functions Im using:

```
def c1(x):
    return np.correlate(x,x,'full')
def c2(x):
    return np.convolve(x,x[::-1])
def c3(x):
    return np.int16(np.rint(signal.fftconvolve(x,x[::-1])))
def c4(x):
    return np.int16(np.rint(signal.correlate(x,x,method='fft')))
```

Its all good for simple arrays, I even created a method that checks for large random numpy arrays, they give back the same result:

```
for i in range(1000):
    x = np.random.randint(-200,200,100000)
    r1,r2,r3,r4 = c1(x),c2(x),c3(x),c4(x)
    if not (np.allclose(r1,r2) and np.allclose(r1,r3) and np.allclose(r1,r4)):
        return x
```

It hasn't failed once.
However when I try them on real sound data (read from a wav by scipy) it turns out that **c1(x)=c2(x)!=c3(x)=c4(x)**.
I also noticed that c3(x) and c4(x) has the same exact values as c1(x) and c2(x), **except that they have large chunks of 0-s in many places** (especially in the center) where c1 and c2 dont. Apart from those missing values they are the same.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Why are there missing values (0-s) in c3 and c4, and why does this happen only when Im processing real wavs and not random arrays?
Thanks.

### EDIT

Here is an example array (600 in length) for which the functions' results dont match:

```
array([ 1048,  1052,  1122,  1066,   972,   992,  1086,  1072,  1099,
        1308,  1373,  1388,  1581,  1749,  1781,  1928,  2122,  2158,
        2308,  2539,  2654,  2787,  3071,  3193,  3196,  3328,  3154,
        2896,  2771,  2529,  2231,  1952,  1616,  1157,   760,   406,
         -31,  -518,  -897, -1229, -1512, -1769, -2099, -2420, -2755,
       -3124, -3486, -3697, -3821, -3965, -3970, -3914, -3932, -3935,
       -3952, -3971, -3974, -3913, -3826, -3741, -3621, -3529, -3465,
       -3381, -3257, -3097, -2875, -2562, -2299, -2069, -1805, -1598,
       -1388, -1197,  -931,  -645,  -355,   -10,   307,   610,   840,
         989,  1153,  1356,  1471,  1567,  1719,  1809,  1760,  1700,
        1649,  1552,  1476,  1407,  1292,  1187,  1049,   886,   741,
         529,   299,    94,  -107,  -302,  -454,  -613,  -752,  -909,
       -1129, -1288, -1442, -1604, -1689, -1806, -1959, -2042, -2115,
       -2223, -2271, -2334, -2380, -2383, -2335, -2243, -2170, -2114,
       -2063, -1985, -1927, -1795, -1689, -1567, -1402, -1235, -1034,
        -858,  -720,  -639,  -528,  -396,  -249,   -92,    36,   153,
         253,   323,   363,   456,   520,   572,   667,   741,   825,
         818,   821,   880,   876,   884,   928,   958,   985,   990,
         963,   902,   858,   776,   723,   683,   627,   582,   509,
         466,   383,   305,   219,   142,   116,    85,    54,    17,
         -17,   -72,   -81,   -46,   -39,     3,    84,   113,   130,
         179,   222,   261,   296,   310,   356,   432,   474,   558,
         623,   633,   689,   787,   846,   882,   957,  1027,  1098,
        1169,  1202,  1233,  1271,  1291,  1376,  1378,  1370,  1419,
        1377,  1359,  1365,  1332,  1301,  1285,  1177,  1128,  1108,
        1009,   944,   909,   844,   759,   722,   655,   616,   564,
         520,   510,   514,   467,   410,   428,   396,   410,   475,
         531,   567,   609,   645,   715,   787,   865,   943,   993,
        1111,  1215,  1333,  1416,  1412,  1450,  1669,  1880,  1933,
        2038,  2200,  2325,  2417,  2528,  2683,  2854,  3052,  3276,
        3504,  3697,  3917,  4163,  4338,  4313,  4098,  3846,  3571,
        3100,  2475,  2011,  1621,  1125,   763,   598,   339,   -62,
        -528, -1038, -1606, -2171, -2748, -3271, -3671, -4002, -4294,
       -4436, -4478, -4600, -4672, -4583, -4451, -4454, -4449, -4383,
       -4371, -4416, -4513, -4553, -4499, -4378, -4187, -3933, -3642,
       -3432, -3192, -2966, -2804, -2696, -2557, -2282, -1996, -1720,
       -1396, -1013,  -680,  -362,    64,   518,   918,  1301,  1580,
        1798,  1987,  2071,  2131,  2220,  2305,  2348,  2394,  2472,
        2473,  2403,  2327,  2222,  2009,  1745,  1536,  1310,  1068,
         813,   540,   289,    87,   -87,  -261,  -439,  -597,  -747,
        -880, -1055, -1246, -1407, -1595, -1748, -1868, -1967, -2043,
       -2078, -2112, -2206, -2272, -2316, -2365, -2440, -2486, -2516,
       -2531, -2534, -2491, -2393, -2309, -2163, -1981, -1814, -1638,
       -1433, -1236, -1102,  -976,  -824,  -656,  -472,  -253,   -34,
         111,   297,   456,   543,   620,   748,   834,   859,   890,
         915,   925,   942,   962,   972,   982,  1003,  1029,   999,
         968,   904,   848,   757,   677,   602,   536,   470,   418,
         375,   282,   209,   138,    55,   -47,  -157,  -243,  -330,
        -429,  -468,  -477,  -493,  -517,  -509,  -510,  -467,  -357,
        -289,  -251,  -201,  -125,   -59,    -1,    97,   206,   334,
         463,   597,   700,   783,   897,   981,  1030,  1030,  1032,
        1094,  1153,  1176,  1193,  1187,  1173,  1191,  1223,  1228,
        1220,  1222,  1189,  1102,  1046,  1042,  1049,  1007,   982,
         952,   885,   877,   907,   839,   746,   716,   652,   638,
         628,   540,   483,   533,   474,   434,   461,   448,   469,
         420,   410,   514,   527,   444,   450,   456,   461,   546,
         653,   778,   962,  1115,  1284,  1369,  1365,  1465,  1588,
        1632,  1657,  1737,  1804,  1973,  2118,  2157,  2257,  2365,
        2465,  2497,  2626,  2750,  2765,  2696,  2755,  2960,  3020,
        3094,  3315,  3632,  3837,  3980,  4042,  3927,  3592,  3067,
        2474,  1995,  1582,  1225,  1047,   905,   778,   492,    30,
        -486, -1079, -1802, -2394, -2845, -3289, -3617, -3865, -4141,
       -4392, -4595, -4756, -4711, -4586, -4440, -4328, -4287, -4335,
       -4466, -4543, -4581, -4571, -4445, -4179, -3824, -3514, -3265,
       -3093, -2956, -2859, -2796, -2668, -2473, -2224, -2034, -1852,
       -1645, -1415, -1166,  -778,  -338,    36,   443,   788,  1051,
        1242,  1355,  1391,  1486,  1661,  1869], dtype=int16)
```

Running a simple checking on it we get:

```
i:  594 c1(x)[i]:  -11191 c4(x)[i]:  0
i:  595 c1(x)[i]:  8216 c4(x)[i]:  0
i:  596 c1(x)[i]:  -32326 c4(x)[i]:  0
i:  597 c1(x)[i]:  -30734 c4(x)[i]:  0
i:  598 c1(x)[i]:  -23815 c4(x)[i]:  0
i:  599 c1(x)[i]:  4296 c4(x)[i]:  0
i:  600 c1(x)[i]:  -23815 c4(x)[i]:  0
i:  601 c1(x)[i]:  -30734 c4(x)[i]:  0
i:  602 c1(x)[i]:  -32326 c4(x)[i]:  0
i:  603 c1(x)[i]:  8216 c4(x)[i]:  0
i:  604 c1(x)[i]:  -11191 c4(x)[i]:  0
```

As you can see in the middle of the autocorrelation in symmetric pattern there are zeros where there shouldnt be.

Comment: you're possibly not doing something wrong. tell us more about the `x` for which things aren't equal, and what the difference is to those where they are.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for asking, I've added an example array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By converting to `np.int16`, you're hitting integer overflow and wrapping the values around.  I assume this is not intentional, since the output looks much more sane without it.

int16 is limited to values from −32,768 through +32,767, but the output of the convolution goes from −1,255,891,038 to +2,459,046,088:

np.int16:

[image: wrapped]

np.int64:

[image: not wrapped]

You can make your test array `float` or `int64` format to handle the required level, and remove the `np.int16` conversion after convolution, then all 4 methods are identical.